# MySQL get rows between max(value) and the second highest value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have problem with sql query. I got in table data like this:

```
Name    Value    Other
Jim      301      v1
Jim      302      v1
Jim      303      v1
Mat      30      else
Mat      301     else
Mat      3091    else
```

And im try to get Name and max(value) column for name and the second highest value for the same name and also do it for all names in single select. Anyone have idea how to do this ? 
Example output : Mat,3091,301 ; Jim,303,302

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: please add expected result in question

Comment: @NikhilVC done, so u got any idea ?

Comment: So this is MySQL?

Comment: What is your primary key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select rows with top two values for each name (MySQL):

```
select t.*
from myTable t
where t.value >= (
    select t1.value
    from myTable t1
    where t1.name = t.name
    order by t1.value desc
    limit 1 offset 1 -- second highest value
)
```

Comment: Thanks that was what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

The standard SQL way would use `rank()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             rank() over (partition by name order by value desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Note:  If there are ties, then this returns more than two rows for each name.